# Problems setting alternatingItemColors from CSS style (Flex)

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

Hopefully simple question: I'm trying to set the alternatingItemColors on a datagrid via some values that I set in a CSS file but nothing seems to work.

the CSS file looks something like this:

```
.FACS0 {color: #B0B0B0;}

.SACS0 {color: #A6A6A6;}

.AICS0
{
    alternatingItemColors: #B0B0B0, #A6A6A6;
}
```

I tried a variety of different things. First I tried to load AICS0 directly, i.e.

```
dataGrid.setStyle("alternatingItemColors", "AICS0");
```

but this leads to a run time error

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion
>   failed: cannot convert "AICS0" to
>   Array.

I then tried

```
dataGrid.setStyle("alternatingItemColors", ["FACS0", "SACS0"]);
```

this runs fine but all rows are set to black.

Note: this

```
dataGrid.setStyle("alternatingItemColors", [0xFF00CC, 0x112200]);
```

works just fine - unfortunately this won't work for me, i.e. I need to be able to load data from a CSS file.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [styleName property](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#styleName)

```
dataGrid.styleName = "AICS0"
```

Comment: Amarghosh - this compiles and runs fine but has no effect - which i find fascinating. Any other thoughts? Thank you for now!

Comment: @fred try setting the `styleName` mxml itself and see if it has any effects. Have you included the CSS properly?

Comment: OK, found the bug. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **ALL** of your `DataGrids` to have the same alternating colors, use this in your CSS:

```
DataGrid
{
    alternating-item-colors: #B0B0B0, #A6A6A6;
}
```